# Codeigniter cache auto refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I´m making a Codeigniter app which make a intense use of

```
$this->db->cache_on();
$this->db->cache_off();
```

in its model Class.

But sometimes I want to clear that cache for a renew of data.

I just make some cron jobs to do that, but, an idea come into my mind. Is there a way to pass a int variable to that method, for auto-destruct cache data after n second/minutes?

Something like

```
$this->db->cache_on(30);
```

and the cache auto-destruct after 30 min.
Could be a good idea, just I don't know how implement it.
Thanks!

Comment: At the moment the user would leave the page the script will end. Therefore, you can't rely on this approach. If the user exists before those 30 minutes are over - the cache won't be cleared. Just my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but figure out a high traffic web, when you need cache for a specific element in a DB for two or three minutes, cold optimize a lot, no?